# DevTools Coverage Activity

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage, chrome-canary

I want to remove unused code from my files and I am using the Coverage tab from DevTools. My problem is that Coverage shows only used code from the static page, if I have styles(hovers for example) or scripts that are not active on page load, Coverage shows them as unused code. Is there any way to force load all inactive scripts and styles so Coverage will show them as used code and not unused?